# How to write MacOS display driver

Tags: macos, iokit

I need to write display driver on MacOS High Sierra for external display. I found IOKit sample for device driver and basic document about IOVideoDevice. But I cannot find detail  document or sample code with IOVideoDevice.

I joined Apple developer program for $99/year. Do I have to join special Apple program for writing video driver? I wonder how graphic card vendor, DisplayLink and AirParrot got the information.

Answer (score 5):

By "video driver" do you mean a video capture device or a graphics card (GPU)?

- `IOVideoDevice` implies a video capture device, e.g. webcam or video capture card. However, this API is old, nowadays drivers for video capture devices should be [written as CoreMediaIO plugins](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/CoreMediaIO/Introduction/Intro.html). (Though since the prevalence of the Library Validation
  code signing flag, this route also has issues, such as 3rd party capture drivers not working with FaceTime and similar apps; this goes beyond the scope of this question.)
- "Graphics card" suggests you have a device you want to use as a display for the Mac. This is not officially supported by Apple. It used to be that you could create an `IOFramebuffer` subclass. As of macOS 10.13 this no longer works as expected (blank screen), and does not work at all as of 10.13.4-10.13.6. The GPU manufacturers (Intel, AMD, and NVidia) are suppliers to Apple, so they get deep access to the graphics pipeline. The APIs they use to implement their drivers are not public.

  **Update:** As of 10.14 and 10.15, `IOFramebuffer` subclasses sort of work again. At least, sufficiently so that the OS extends the display are to such a virtual screen, although the "vram" is never actually filled with the image data. You need to capture that in user space via Core Graphics APIs or similar.

Comment: Thanks for the closure @pmdj. I can't find it because it isn't available. Oh well.